# How to add additional text string to print on specific rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to print the index name then mute index number from the print. I then want to add specfic text to specific columns. I want to also mute the top row.

```
Current code:
d=((d*100).round(2)).astype(str) + '%'
d='Prob animal=('+ d.reset_index() + ')'
print(d)

Current output:

  index    black 
0 animal                    
1 Prob animal=(bird)    Prob animal=(33.33%) 
2 Prob animal=(cat)     Prob animal=(50.00%) 
3 Prob animal=(dog)     Prob animal=(0.00%)  

Expected output:

Prob animal=(bird)    =33.33%  
Prob animal=(cat)     =50.00%  
Prob animal=(dog)     =0.00%
```

Comment: Writing to file preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `header=False` to the `DataFrame.to_string()` and `DataFrame.to_csv()` methods.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['bird', 0.33333333],
    ['cat',  0.50000000],
    ['dog',  0.00000000],
]
columns = ['animal', 'black']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df.set_index('animal', inplace=True)
df.index = map(lambda x: 'Prob animal=({})'.format(x), df.index)
df['black'] = df['black'].apply(lambda x: '={:0>5.2f}%'.format(100 * x))

print(df.to_string(header=False))
df.to_csv('output.csv', header=False)
```